# I'm new to python and this is the problem;\

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import socket
my_socket=socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',8820))
my_socket.send('Hadar')
data=my_socket.recv(1024)
print ('The server sent: '+data)
my_socket.close()
```

It says: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

When I put a 'b' before this line:

```
my_socket.send(b'Haddar')
```

It says `"TypeError: must be str, not bytes"`
and I do want the output in string type to write "Hello:(that what the server send) Hadar(that what the client send)

Comment: Have you tried to put a `b` in front of the greeting message too ? `print(b'The server sent: ' + data)`

Comment: Do you get the erros on the same line (the `send` method?)

Comment: Which line is throwing the first `TypeError`?

Comment: Please update your question with the traceback.

Comment: @JoseKilo yes I have... still doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the string in `utf-8` before sending it.

Just call `"random_string".encode()` method while sending and `.decode()` while recieving.

More info at https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

This must work:

```
my_socket.send('Hadar'.encode())
...
print ('The server sent: '+data.decode())
```

Comment: It is work but it print: The server sent:    without whatthe server sent...

Comment: @user12519892 That totally depends on what your server side script is sending.

Comment: `import socket
my_socket=socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',8820))
my_socket.send('Hadar'.encode())
data=my_socket.recv(1024)
print ('The server sent: '+data.decode())
my_socket.close()`